# Answering homework questions and questions of similar type

Tags: discussion

The question i am referring to is [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/287851/a-circuit-that-can-count-the-number-of-buttons-not-being-pressed).

I am sorry if it is just my presumption but i feel, i see a pattern.

**Pattern 1:**
Home work questions - Logic gates, Fourier, K-Map, communication bit rate, etc straight away gets closed - Most of the time

**Pattern 2**
The questions similar to the one linked above - gets answers soon. Normally multiple. Another example [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/287827/controlling-momentary-switch-controlled-machine-with-programmable-socket). Please take it lightly, i have answered a part too in this question.

1. Both patterns demonstrate no efforts from OP.
2. Both can be called straightaway home work or assignment topics.

But, why pattern 2 rarely gets closed?

**My opinion:** Answer both patterns so that, it will be helpful to others.
 Please let me know your views.

Comment: I don't see in any way how the second question mentioned is a homework question. It looks by someone who a) is out of his comfort zone and b) has already thought about it and identified the most difficult part and is only asking about ideas, not complete solutions/components. Its not a stellar question, but clearly within the realm of designing stuff.

Comment: @PlasmaHH i would also add that questions which are more theoretical(assignments) and with no background efforts made visible will be closed sooner. Questions which are practical, and solutions are available in various forms are more supported than the former one.

Comment: also maybe he just saw this guy and wants to repeat it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCcO-6lb9zM ... anyways, I am wondering what the point of your comment and to an extent that of your question is. We don't do homework. We gladly help if you are stuck at a specific point with your homework and need help to advance that one step. Similarily we are not a design service, we help with advancing a project by a step, but don't do the whole project

Comment: @PlasmaHH I love to take help from others when i am stuck too. For the attached question on displaying the "no. of switches which are not activated on a 7 segment display", i can assume that it is part of the OP's big project OR also it is just the assignment which has been posted here as a question. No efforts were made visible to others in the question by the OP too. May i ask you what would you prefer to do. Answer it / ask for efforts/ignore? All these, i am doing only to understand how to respond to those kind of questions when i think, i have  solution. Thanks

Comment: for that first one I would personally vtc as too broad, one could write books and still not fully answer it.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Yes. Thanks. Now, i can see some differences in the two questions i had linked to. the coffee one is more towards a practical solution for a practical need which is clear, while the other one is not so clear.

Comment: Neither example you offer is a HW question.

Comment: The negative votes :)

Comment: Pattern 2 doesn't get closed as much because, as PlasmaHH said, they are not homework questions at all. Just questions from guys that want to build something, but they don't know how to proceed. This is much nicer to answer than questions where students just post a scan of their exercise book and expect to get the work done for them. In pattern 2, OP is usually willing to learn, although he is often unable to formulate things clearly. Now, my opinion: it does **not** actually help the careless student to answer his hw question (at least not in the way he expects it). Give a Man a Fish, etc...

Comment: Moreover, homework questions are often totally on the opposite side of world realities. Like, "how do you do this, using only JK flip-flops?" - seriously, who had to face this in real life? So it really makes them boring, and unuseful to others, except maybe for the next unconcerned student that will be given the exact same exercise.

Comment: @dim Thanks Dim. Well said. I agree with your points fully.

Comment: @dim I have added your suggestion as an answer. Let me know if it is okay.

Comment: @Umar No problem, and I gave you an upvote (since I totally agree with that).

Answer (score 2):

@dim with your permission..

Pattern 2 doesn't get closed as much because, as PlasmaHH said, they are not homework questions at all. Just questions from guys that want to build something, but they don't know how to proceed. This is much nicer to answer than questions where students just post a scan of their exercise book and expect to get the work done for them. In pattern 2, OP is usually willing to learn, although he is often unable to formulate things clearly. Now, my opinion: it does not actually help the careless student to answer his hw question (at least not in the way he expects it). Give a Man a Fish, etc.